# Silverlight app delayed loading on computer without internet connection

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-server-2012

When I try to open an intranet webpage with an embedded Silverlight application on a Windows Server 2012 computer with latest released Silverlight plugin installed and no internet connection, the status bar of the browser shows 'Connecting to go.microsoft.com' and then does not load the silverlight application for the next 15 - 20 seconds.

Network traffic analysis shows that the URL http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376 is called before loading the .xap file(which is already cached in client side - status 304 "Not Modified")

After the previously mentioned 20 seconds or so, it loads the Silverlight .xap file successfully. 
Could anyone please tell me why this delay is happening even when the Silverlight plugin is installed and the .xap file can be loaded successfully?

I have tried on Internet Explorer 10 and Firefox 38. Same result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the case that the Silverlight application is signed with a code-signing certificate. During the initialization of the SL application, the SL runtime tries to validate this certificate. One step of this validation process is called "certificate revocation check" if this is enabled in IE (it is by default). In Internet Explorer, open Tools --> Internet Options --> Advanced tab --> "Check for publisher's certificate revocation". Try disabling this feature and restart your browser.

Another approach could be lowering the default timeout value of certificate revocation check which is a group policy setting. A good starting point for that is [How Certificate Revocation Works](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619754%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).